# how to use babelbib

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I am using sharelatex.com and having problems with the package babelbib. I suppose it's just a problem of placing of the different items. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{(italian)}
\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\title{mytitle}
\author{myname}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduzione}
\onehalfspacing
Qualcosa su Weber \citep{turner1983weber}.

\medskip
\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong, missing or misplaced? I want to have a document with references in Italian. refs.bib is where i stored my references (for instance, turner1983weber). Multiple errror messages come out and I cannot find a way to cope with all of them being new to latex :).

Comment: You are mixing biblatex commands (`\printbibliography`) and "standard" commands. I would suggest to switch to biblatex completly and to drop babelbib. (I don't know if sharelatex can use biber but if not you could use the bibtex backend).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i usually employ natbib. is there a way to change the language in which references will be displayed with natbib? It's really just a matter of translating "pages" in Italian..

Comment: It is really much easier to do this in biblatex (and you can use the natbib option and use command like `\citep`).

Comment: @gmari `babelbib` and `natbib` aren't compatible; either you don't get author-year with `babelbib` or the bibliography is not localized with `natbib`. You find some non standard `natbib_ita` around the net. But the best is switching to `biblatex`.